# ArrayList.contains for ArrayList with Hashmaps

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have this `ArrayList` of hashmaps -- > `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`

How can I easily check if the hashmap contains certain value ? I don't want to manually iterate through the whole list. I am looking for an alternative of `ArrayList.contains()` which works for this case.

Eg : Say I put the following values to Hashmap

```
map.put(TAG_ID, id);
map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTON, description);
```

and then add keep adding this to my ArrayList - `arrayList.add(map)` The thing is, I dont want to add duplicated id to the arraylist.

Comment: "How can I easily check if the hashmap contains certain value ?" Which hashmap, you can have many in the ArrayList?

Comment: First question - why to use `ArrayList`???

Comment: "The thing is, I dont want to add duplicated id to the arraylist. " I think you should redesign your structures.

Comment: @peter.petrov yeah I keep adding new hashmaps - each will have a id field as shown in the example.If the hasmap with certain id is added to the list, I dont want to add again to avoid duplication.

Comment: @peter.petrov This is a part of a bigger project. Redesign at this point is tough :( I think I want a custom `contains()` which search in the hashmap for id.

Answer (score 1):

You should rethink your design.  Use an object instead of a `Map` to represent what you're storing.  Then use a `Map` to keep track of the collection of said objects.  This will automatically handle the duplicates case you've mentioned, and will prevent you from having to store multiple `Map`s and iterate through them.

```
public class Item {
  String id;
  String title;
  String description;
}

HashMap<String, Item> map = new HashMap<String, Item>();
map.put(item.id, item);
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this keeping the current design? This is actually a part of an Android project - the arraylist values are used a lot at other instances.

Comment: If you have the freedom to change everything, I'd go with my answer.  If you must continue using `Map`s to represent the entities, I'd go with [peter.petrov's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21649791/722760).  If you must continue using `Map`s and `ArrayList`s, then I don't think you have any option but to write a custom `contains` function that iterates through the list and checks each map, as you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

1) Based on your 1st comment, you should think of using
`HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`.

For key of the external HashMap use the ID value from the internal HashMaps.
For the internal HashMaps, just keep doing what you do already.

2) Based on your 2nd comment, you may think of extending ArraList and
overrding contains but this sounds to me like overkill and the wrong way
to go in general. `ArrayList.contains()` is still iterating and checking,
I don't see why you don't want to iterate in your case.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this suppose you have an arraylist called list contain three hashmaps

```
 for(HashMap<String ,String> h : list)
     {
         String name =h.get("name");
         String age= h.get("age");
         String address =h.get("address");

         //some code here for the var :)
     }
```

Comment: The OP stated that he doesn't want to manually iterate through the lists. (Whether it is possible or not, I do not know yet now)